# How many users can access simultaneously an C# WPF app which is stored in a shared directory?

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

My plan is to make an app which would be stored in some shared directory and also it would be connected to SQLite database, so I was thinking If that would cause some problems or is it impossible to do that?

Comment: why wouldn't each eligible user have it's own local copy of the application?

Comment: Read about how SQLite handles multiuser access https://sqlite.org/faq.html#q5

Comment: I was also thinking about that, and in that case I can put a database in shared folder. I'm not allowed to conmect to database via web.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html): *6.0 How To Corrupt Your Database Files ... Your best defense is to not use SQLite for files on a network filesystem.*

Comment: Which database do you recommend to use in this case?